# How to get controller and action name in ErrorController

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I get a controller and an action name in the ErrorController? I mean the controller and action where an exception occurred. For example, if I go to:

```
/bogusController/bogusAction
```

I would like to get "bogusController" and "bogusAction". Calling:

```
$this->_request->getControllerName();
$this->_request->getActionName();
```

Returns "error" and "error".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Original request is stored in error_handler param: `$this->_getParam('error_handler')->request->getControllerName();`

Some docs:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler